# What are HTML 4 media specifiers

Tags: html, media-queries, html4

Can some one explain to me what HTML 4 media specifiers are? Is there docs that explain this?

Comment: No I mean HTML 4 media specifier as some one stated in my last question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760361/html5-css-media-queries-operators-question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, you mean
*MediaDesc*

> Attribute values of type `MediaDesc` are media descriptors — a
>   comma-separated list of media for which the linked resource is
>   tailored. Media descriptors are *case-sensitive*.
>
> The following **media descriptors** are defined in HTML 4:
>
> - **screen**, for non-paged computer screens;
> - **tty**, for fixed-pitch character grid displays (such as the display used by [Lynx](http://lynx.browser.org/));
> - **tv**, for television-type devices with low resolution and limited scrollability;
> - **projection**, for projectors;
> - **handheld**, for handheld devices (characterized by a small display and limited bandwidth);
> - **print**, for output to a printer;
> - **braille**, for braille tactile feedback devices;
> - **aural**, for speech synthesizers;
> - **all**, for all devices.

from http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/values.html

At first I thought you were asking about CONTENT types, like text/html, image/jpeg, audio/mpeg, video/quicktime, text/css, and text/javascript.

See http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/index.html

Comment: So HTML 4 media specifiers is the same as HTML 4 media descriptors?

Comment: Probably.  As you can see from the responses, the term "media specifiers" is not familiar to anyone here, in the context of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the context you're speaking of, but maybe someone is using it to refer to [CSS media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html) (or explained in [one tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp))?

**UPDATED ANSWER PER COMMENT**:

Media queries are explained in the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) and at https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Media_queries

But the point is that these were not all available in HTML4, so see the list of media types above.

Comment: Actually the question spawns from my last question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760361/html5-css-media-queries-operators-question

Answer (score 0):

They tell what type of screen etc. the content is viewable on. For example there is the `print` media where you can define what the printed content looks like (so you can remove excess colors etc.).

I hope this helps.